# How to match a pattern multiple times within a string and replace them

Tags: regex

I want to find all instances of Foo inside #include preprocessor using regex. so far, I can only match one instance using this pattern `#include "(.*?)Foo(.*?)"`. and to replace Foo with Bar i use this substitution `#include "$1Bar$2"`

When I replace Foo with Bar, the following example

```
#include "abcFoo1/Foo123/aFoo"
```

becomes

```
#include "abcBar1/Foo123/aFoo"
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to make it match all instances of Foo within the #include statement and get the following result after replacement.

```
#include "abcBar1/Bar123/aBar"
```

P.S. I'm trying to do this for many strings using a text editor such as Notepad++ or IDE like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in e.g. Notepad++ (or anything that uses PCRE) if you want to do it in one go:

```
(?:#include ".*?|(?<!^)\G.*?)\KFoo
```

Breakdown:

- `(?:#include ".*?|(?<!^)\G.*?)` - non-captured group with 2 alternatives:

1. `#include ".*?` - the start of your string followed by non-greedily matched anything
2. `(?<!^)\G.*?` - `\G` is the position at the end of previous match, followed by non-greedy anything as above. Using `\G` is required here, since otherwise the regex engine won't match the same parts twice. `(?<!^)` negative lookbehind of the start of the line is there to not match cases in which there would be something with `Foo` above `#include`s (as `\G` starts at the start of the string), which shouldn't happen and is likely optional, but included it just in case, for a full solution.

- `\K` - don't include anything before this in the match, so that only the next part gets matched
- `Foo` - the part that you want to replace

We're matching only `Foo`s, so the replacement should be just `Bar`.

Also, in Notepad++, `. matches newline` option needs to be turned off.

[Demo with detailed explantation](https://regex101.com/r/JORNv6/1)

Answer (score 1):

On Notepad++ or Sublime text, you click Ctrl+H, you get the find+replace bar,
you write Foo in the find field, then Bar in the Replace, and it should be good.

no need for a complex regex pattern I believe.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, but I want to do this on many cpp and header files. so I don't want to replace Foo with Bar outside of #include statement.

Comment: I think you need to use lookbehind (for #include) and try to match Foo and replace it, this will change first occurrence in each one contains #include. however, I guess it will need to be executed multiple times to have the result you want.

an alternative, run a python script on your cpp file and it will fix all your issue, here is a sample code:  
import re
pattern = r'(?<=#include.*)Foo'
new_string = re.sub(pattern, 'Bar', string) #left for your the string to be read from the file
print(new_string)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for a string with `Foo` to replace it with `Bar`, look for `Foo` which has `#include` behind

```
(?=Foo)(?<=#include .*)Foo
```

or

```
Foo(?<=#include .*Foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filename should be between double quotes, and you don't want to match crossing a double quote by itself:

```
(?:#include\h+"(?=[^"\r\n]*")|\G(?!^))[^"\r\n]*?\KFoo
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `#include\h+"` Match `#include` followed by 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
  - `(?=[^"\r\n]*")` Positive lookahead, assert a `"` to the right on the same line
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, not at the start of the string
- `)` Close the non capture goru
- `[^"\r\n]*?` Match optional chars other than `"` or a newline
- `\KFoo` Forget what is matches so far and match `Foo`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K1bvrn/1)

If the string should not contain spaces, you can use `\s` in the negated character class:

```
(?:#include\h+"(?=[^"\s]*")|\G(?!^))[^"\s]*?\KFoo
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MKtQba/1)